# Access Check Failed! on ui:inputText component event after Apex call

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, event, lightning, pre-release

I've got a really basic component which call an Apex method when we press the Enter key. However, since Spring'16, I've got the following warning message:

**WARNING: Access Check Failed! Component.getEvent():'keyup' of component 'markup://ui:inputText {5:2;a}' is not visible to 'markup://[MyNameSpace]:TestApp {1:2;a}'.**

This warning is not displayed when I enter values in my *ui:inputText*, but as soon as I hit Enter (and thus, call my Apex method), entering new values in the field will generate this warning.

I don't understand why this happen, nor do I understand why it only happens after the Apex call. I feel like I'm missing something important about event management in Lightning, so I would like to understand.

I just kept the minimum here so that it's easier to understand:

**TestApp.app**:

```
<aura:application >
    <c:TestInput />
</aura:application>
```

**TestInput.cmp**:

```
<aura:component controller="TestInput">
    <ui:inputText keyup="{!c.getInput}"/>    
</aura:component>
```

**TestInputController.js**:

```
({
    getInput : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(event);
        if(event.getParam('keyCode') == 13){
            console.log('OK');
            helper.getValueFromServer(component);
        }
    }
})
```

**TestInputHelper.js**:

```
({
    getValueFromServer : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getValueFromServer");

        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log('Callout OK');             
            }  
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**TestInput.apxc**:

```
public class TestInput {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getValueFromServer() {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

If anyone understands, thanks in advance for the explanation.

Comment: check the documetation https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf  Page no 192 `Anatomy of an Access Check Warning`

Comment: Thanks @Ratan I've seen this, but unfortunately I still don't understand why this only happens after the Apex call

Comment: @FabienTaillon Weird i don't get error with your code .

Comment: Sorry I forgot to explain something: this warning is displayed in the browser console, not in the UI directly. But as explained in the doc (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/access_intro.htm), "The framework will enforce these access checks more strictly in the future so you shouldn’t ignore them". So I would like to understand now. Also the warning is displayed only in a Spring'16 org.

Comment: I'm getting it too. WARNING: Access Check Failed! Component.getEvent():'blur' of component 'markup://ui:inputText {22:1;0} {lookup}' is not visible to 'markup://c:SOL_LookupContainer {1:2;a}'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyup event is inherited from the uiEvents interface as is `access="GLOBAL"` so I think this might be a bug in the access checks logic. I'm pulling in the folks that implemented client side access checks for their help now.

Comment: Yes pretty sure this is a bug in our framework components code. We'll be trying to patch it.

Comment: Thanks Doug and Kris. I'll just wait for you to confirm, and select it as best answer then :)

Comment: I'm also getting this error on both KeyUp and KeyDown which are the two events that I am handling and invoking a controller method.

Comment: Any updates on this?  I just started getting the same error this afternoon.

Comment: Also getting the same issue. Access warnings being generated after a call to the server. No access warnings before. Any updates?

Comment: I've tried in a Summer '16 pre-release org, and I don't have the issue anymore so it seems to be fixed, thanks !

Comment: In Summer 17, again this error is comping but now on for ui:inputDateTime. 
Looks a bug again. @doug-chasman (or any other) can you please confirm if its a bug again in version 40.0.