# Access Check Failed! even though component is marked with access of global

Tags: lightning-aura-components, access

I am getting the following warning in the console even though my component is marked as access="global". This makes no sense to me. Is it possibly an issue with the debugger?

These are the warnings I get in the console whenever I click the checkbox.

> WARNING: Access Check Failed! Component.getEvent():'click' of
>   component 'markup://ui:inputCheckbox {22:37;a}' is not visible to ....
>
> WARNING: Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute
>   'disableDoubleClicks' of component 'markup://ui:inputCheckbox
>   {22:37;a}' .....
>
> aura_proddebug.js:14495 WARNING: Access Check Failed!
>   Component.getEvent():'change' of component 'markup://ui:inputCheckbox
>   {22:37;a}'...

and this is the component code:

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="ListRacesController">
<aura:attribute name="races" type="Race__c[]"  />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<!-- key here is that the handler has no name attribute specified when dealing with application event -->
<aura:handler event="c:addToRaceList" action="{!c.handleAddToRaces}" />

<ltng:require styles="/resource/slds100/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"/>
<div class="slds">
    <div class="slds-m-around--small slds-p-top--large">
        <div class="slds-card">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.races}" var="race">
                <header class="slds-card__header">
                    <ui:outputText class="slds-text-heading--label" value="{!race.Name}" />
                </header>
                <section class="slds-card__body">
                    <div class="slds-tile slds-hint-parent">
                        <p class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate">Race Type: 
                            <ui:outputText value="{!race.Type__c}" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="slds-truncate">Location: 
                            <ui:outputText value="{!race.Location__c}"/>
                        </p>
                        <p class="slds-truncate">Date/Time:
                            <ui:outputDateTime value="{!race.DateTime__c}" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="slds-truncate">Attended?
                            <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!race.Attended__c}" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="slds-truncate">Results: 
                            <ui:outputTextArea value="{!race.Results__c}"/>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </aura:iteration>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the complete access check error message - the part after the ellipses is important.

BTW access="globa;" on your component has no bearing on these access check errors since they are about the things that are marked access= in ui:inputCheckbox.

Comment: Hi Doug, yes after the ellipses for all the messages it is just this: to 'markup://c:RaceTrackerApp {1:2;a}'. Which is the name of my container app, along with it's global ID.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about how it is pointing to the ui:inputcheckbox as the problem, but that is not a component I have control over, which is why I was thinking this might be an issue with the debugger.

Comment: Normally I would not care about a warning that does not affect anything, but this is code for a course I am designing for Pluralsight about Lightning and part of the course has us looking at the console for messages and these are showing up. I cannot just pretend that they are not there without having some kind of explanation for why. That was why I wanted to know if it was just a problem with the client side access checks as I saw in someone elses post about a similar issue. Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you know whether this might have anything to do with the issue reported here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105528/access-check-failed-on-uiinputtext-component-event-after-apex-call

Comment: Very likely the same issue - I'm going to ping the team/developer that owns the bug on the other thread again.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me when I had the lightning component debugger on. When I disabled the user from the lightning debugger, it went away. I hope it helps.