# Access Check Failed! on ui:spinner component event after Apex call

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, ui

I am getting a very similar problem to [this problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105528/access-check-failed-on-uiinputtext-component-event-after-apex-call) with the **ui:spinner**. I am also using a Summer 16 org.

The warning message I get is the following:

> WARNING: Access Check Failed! Component.getEvent():'toggle' of
>   component 'markup://ui:spinner {9:2;a} {spinner}' is not visible to
>   'markup://c:TestCMP {5:2;a}'.

Using the same TestApp.app and code as below:

**TestApp.app:**

```
<aura:application >
    <c:TestInput />
</aura:application>
```

**TestInput.cmp:**

```
<aura:component controller="TestInput">
    <aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showSpinner}"/>
    <aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideSpinner}"/>

    <center><ui:spinner aura:id="spinner" /></center>
    <ui:inputText keyup="{!c.getInput}"/>    
</aura:component>
```

**TestInputController.js:**

```
({
    showSpinner : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.showSpinner(component, event);
    },
    hideSpinner : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.hideSpinner(component, event);
    }, 
    getInput : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(event);
        if(event.getParam('keyCode') == 13){
            console.log('OK');
            helper.getValueFromServer(component);
        }
    }
})
```

**TestInputHelper.js:**

```
({
    showSpinner : function (component, event) {
        var spinner = component.find("spinner");
        var evt = spinner.get("e.toggle");
        evt.setParams({ isVisible : true });
        evt.fire();    
    },

    hideSpinner : function (component, event) {
        var spinner = component.find("spinner");
        var evt = spinner.get("e.toggle");
        evt.setParams({ isVisible : false });
        evt.fire();   
    },
    getValueFromServer : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getValueFromServer");

        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log('Callout OK');             
            }  
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**TestInput.apxc:**

```
public class TestInput {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getValueFromServer() {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

It looks like another framework bug but I'm not sure why it has been fixed for ui:inputtext and not ui:spinner if that is the case?

Comment: Here is a similar question, you might find it helpful
[Access-check-failed-on-ui : inputtext](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105528/access-check-failed-on-uiinputtext-component-event-after-apex-call?lq=1)

Comment: I already mentioned that at the top and yes it was helpful. It seems like another bug needs to be fixed by SF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around for this is to show/hide the spinner using a lightning attribute on the lightning isVisible attribute

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="spinnerIsVisibile" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<ui:spinner isVisible="{!v.spinnerIsVisibile}" aura:id="spinner"/>
```

Helper:

```
showSpinner : function (component, event) {
    component.set('v.spinnerIsVisibile', true);  
},

hideSpinner : function (component, event) {
    component.set('v.spinnerIsVisibile', false);  
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your example code is missing the ui:spinner component in markup, but assuming `component.find("spinner")` returns a ui:spinner, this is a known issue that has recently been fixed and will most likely be released in an upcoming patch. Exact timetable for release is still uncertain.

Comment: Thanks for editing the example code. This has been fixed internally and should be released in the next couple weeks.